# Changing your username on Delicious

Tags: delicious, username

Is it possible to change your username on Delicious? I have an old account with all my bookmarks and I would like to change my username.

Is the only solution exporting your existing bookmarks from your old account and importing them in your new account? Anyone has experience with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, but you can create a new account and import your exported bookmarks from your old account.

From the Delicious FAQ:

> **How do I change my username?**
>   There's no easy way to do this right now, but
>   you can use the export and import
>   features in your settings to change to
>   a new account while preserving your
>   current bookmarks. First, visit your
>   Settings (accessible from the top
>   right of every page on Delicious) and
>   select export/backup from that page.
>   Follow the directions to export your
>   bookmarks. Then, register or log into
>   your new account, go to settings, and
>   select import/upload. After importing
>   your bookmarks into your new account,
>   you can log out of it and log back
>   into your old account to delete that
>   one. To do this, go to Settings and
>   choose delete account.

Comment: As of now, the import function doesnt seem to work on delicious.com :(